# Errors when compiling OpenCV with GPU Support in Visual Studio C++ Windows10

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11

I am attempting to install OpenCV with CUDA support on a new machine.

I expected the ALL_BUILD target to complete with no errors, allowing me to build the INSTALL target so I could use these modules in a project imported from another computer.

Instead, the ALL_BUILD target had 363 errors and it was not possible to continue building.

OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
CPU: i7-13800H
GPU: NVIDIA RTX A1000 6GB Laptop GPU
C++ Standard: 11
OpenCV version: 4.5.5
OpenCV contrib version: 4.5.5
Visual Studio Version: Visual Studio 17 2022
CUDA version: 12.2
CUDNN version: 8.9.3

WITH_CUDA set to true.
OPENCV_DNN_CUDA set to true.
ENABLE_FAST_MATH set to true.
CUDA_FAST_MATH set to true.
CUDA_ARCH_BIN set to 8.6.

CUDA and CUDNN show up on Cmake GUI.
When I build the ALL_BUILD Cmake target in Visual Studio, I get a total of 363 errors.

Most of these errors fall under 2 categories.

The first seems to be syntax errors in the common.hpp file. Here is a screenshot of the first of these errors:
[common.hpp errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6rtz.png)

The second is a set of linking errors when attempting to compile OpenCV as shown here:
[LINK1181 input file errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMsUX.png)

There are some other errors that occur as well.
I have attached images of them as I am not sure which is important.
[MSB8066 Cuda Filters error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOyIZ.png)

[texture is not a template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOIhB.png)

[no instance of overloaded function in opencv_xfeatures2d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZE9d.png)

Any advice on what to fix would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you also try to build opencv without GPU? Does it work in that case? Can you give a step by step overview about how to build opencv? Are you using CMake GUI, etc.?